# how to add expandable listview inside material design navigation drawer in android?

Tags: android

I want to add expandable listview inside material design navigation drawer in android? like this application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ExpandablelistViewActivity.java:**

```
/**********Expandable Listview Inside Navigation Drawer************/



import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener; 
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener; 
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener; 
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout; 
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ExpandablelistViewActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    FrameLayout actContent;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandablelist_view);

        /************* ExpandableListView **********/

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                ExpandablelistViewActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        //expandAll();
        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            //  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            //  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            expListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }


    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }
}
```

**ExpandablelistViewActivity Layout ::**

```
/*********************ExpandablelistViewActivity Layout *****************************************/

 <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/tropical"
   tools:context="com.example.localization.ExpandablelistViewActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.java:**

```
/****************************ExpandableListAdapter*******************************************/


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
      //  lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**list_group layout :**

```
/*********************    list_group layout*****************************/


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item layout:**

```
/*********************   list_item layout*****************************/


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

< / LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use DrawerLayout and inside it use AnimatedExpandableListView [here](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/blob/master/src/com/idunnololz/widgets/AnimatedExpandableListView.java)

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

<AnimatedExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer_user_courses"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/side_menu_color"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@drawable/line_bettwen_courses"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/expandable_list_indicator" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer_user_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/side_menu_color"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/userinfo_side_menu"></include>
</LinearLayout>
```